# Check if element doesn't have attribute jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

`onClick` of an item it adds an attribute. Only three items can be selected so they'll only ever be three elements on the page with the attribute like : `data-selected: 1`, `data-selected: 2` or `data-selected: 3`.

```
if ($('.item').attr('data-selected', '1') || $('.item').attr('data-selected', '1') || 
    $('.item').attr('data-selected', '1')) {
}
```

I can do an if statement to check if an element has an `attribute`, how do I check if all the elements with `.item` class have an attribute and if not then do something.

Comment: Do you want to check the value of the attribute? Whether the attribute exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)** method instead of `attr()` when you deal with data attributes, and you have to now the difference between data attribute setters and getters.

Setter :

```
$('.item').data('selected', '1'); // assign to the data attribute selected the value 1
```

Getter :

```
$('.item').data('selected'); //get the value 1 from data attribute selected
```

Try to store the value of data attribute `selected` in variable then check :

```
var selected = $('.item').data('selected');

if (selected == 1 || selected ==2 || selected == 3) {
    //Code here
}
```

> how do I check if all the elements with .item class have an attribute and if not then do something.

You could use Jquery not selector **[:not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)** that will selects all elements that do not match the given selector. :

```
if($('.item:not([data-selected])').length)
    //Not all items has attribute data-selected
else
    //All items has attribute data-selected
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This will not work if the attribute is set directly in the HTML; it will only work if the data is set using `.data`.

Comment: No that not true, should work also with data attribute set directly in the HTML.

Comment: `.data()` reads `data-*` attributes but doesn't assign to them.

Comment: Wait, yes, I was thinking the `:data()` selector (from jQuery UI) my bad :)

Comment: Check the documentation please @Oriol, you can see the get and set buttons in the last demo.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki `.data()` can store data but not in `data-*` attributes. https://jsfiddle.net/Ly731bdh/

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Yes, of course `.data()` can read the data set by itself. But that data **is not stored in `data-*` attributes**.

Comment: Why i should care about data stored in data-* attributes, when i can set and get data attributes using data() method.

Answer (score 1):

Just check that your selected elements have the required attribute (or not). You can `.filter` or use the `.not` [traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/filtering/) function.

#### ** UPDATE **

Based on what I understand of this question, you want to restrict selection to only three items. Here's a proposal :

```js
$(function () {
  $('.item').on('click', function () {
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked'); // currently checked?
    var selected = $('.item').filter('[data-selected]');

    if (checked) {
      $(this).attr('data-selected', -1).parent().addClass('selected');
      selected = selected.add(this);
    } else {
      $(this).removeAttr('data-selected').parent().removeClass('selected');
      selected = selected.not(this);
    }

    selected.sort(function (a, b) {
      return $(a).attr('data-selected') - $(b).attr('data-selected');
    }).each(function (index) {
      if (index >= 3) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false).removeAttr('data-selected').parent().removeClass('selected');
      } else {
        $(this).attr('data-selected', index + 1);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.selected { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="item">Item 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="item">Item 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="item">Item 3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="item">Item 4</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="item">Item 5</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="item">Item 6</label>
```

---

**Note**: you may replace `.attr` and `.removeAttr` with `.data` and `.removeData`, however only with the former that you may see changes on the DOM. jQuery data (i.e. `.data`) only keep internal cache of the data and does not affect the DOM tree. Either is fine in your case and this is a matter of choice.

Answer (score 0):

> how do I check if all the elements with .item class have an attribute and if not then do something.

```
var items = $('.item');
var itemsWithoutAttribute = items.filter(':not([data-selected]');
if(itemsWithoutAttribute.length > 0) {
    ...
}
```